# For loop only shows last value of array in r (attempting to combine datasets)

Tags: r, csv, for-loop, import

I think i'm off the beaten path with this, but i'm trying to read in a number of files and combine them into a single dataset `df`. I might not be able to do this like this, but I noticed that `df` has all the observations from the last array in x. Is there a reason for this?

```
  x<-list.files(path=getwd(),pattern=".csv")
  for(i in 1:length(x))
  {
    df<-read.csv(x[i])
  }
```

Comment: you are overwriting the variable in every iteration. Try `df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(x, read.csv))`. **Edit** corrected a minor mistake in do.call (order of call and vector).

Comment: indeed was a bit quick on on the keyboard. It has been corrected.